# powershell script delete first character in output

Tags: powershell

How would I delete the first line in the output from this command? If the output is `A123456`, I just want it to show me `123456` with the `A`.

```
Get-User $_ | Select sAMAccountName
```

Comment: What is the Get-User command?  That doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Do you just want the sAMAccountName string, or do you want an object with the sAMAccountName property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the substring starting at the second letter(index 1).

```
Get-User $_ | Select @{n="AccountName";e={$_.sAMAccountName.Substring(1)}}
```

If you just need the value, you could do it like this:

```
Get-User $_ | % { $_.sAMAccountName.Substring(1) }
```

Comment: Thanks Frode. I just needed the value. I am not that familar with using strings but appreacite your expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Substring(1) returns a substring containing all chars after the first one.

```
Get-User $_ | Select @{N="myAccountName";E={$_.sAMAccountName).substring(1)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the first character with the `-replace` operator:

```
(Get-User $_ | select -Expand sAMAccountName) -replace '^.'
```

Or

```
Get-User $_ | select @{n='sAMAccountName';e={$_.sAMAccountName -replace '^.'}}
```

if you want to keep objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "@123456";
$str = $str.Substring(1,($str.Length-1));
$str;
```